# Grouping values from dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, grouping

I have two tables with data

TAB1

```
    -------------------------
    | ID1 | ID2 |  A    | B |
    |  1  |  8  |'John' | 9 |
    |  2  |  9  |'Smith'| 0 |
```

TAB2

```
   ------------------------------------------
   | NAME | ID1 | ID2 | VSTRING | VINT |ROOT|
   | 'C1' |  1  |  8  |  'R01'  | NULL | 'A'|
   | 'C1' |  1  |  8  |  'R02'  | NULL | 'B'|
   | 'C2' |  1  |  8  |   NULL  | 9991 | 'B'|
   | 'C1' |  2  |  9  |  'D02'  | NULL | 'B'|
```

I need a query which will produce

TAB3

```
    -------------------------------------
    | ID1 | ID2 |   A    |  C1   |  C2  | 
    |  1  |  8  | 'John' | 'R01' | 9991 | 
    |  2  |  9  | 'Smith'| 'D02' | NULL |
```

The TAB1 contains users and IDs. The TAB2 contains columns and values in the dynamic structure. If one cell (see [TAB2.NAME = 'C1' and TAB2.ID1 = 1]) has more than one value then the value associated with ROOT = 'A' should be taken.

The only problem I have is how to pick up the correct value base on the ROOT column. The following code is returning correct structure of TAB3 but the values are incorrect.

```
select t.id1, t.id2, t.a,
    max(case when t2.name = 'C2' then t2.vint end) c2,
    max(case when t2.name = 'C1' then t2.vstring end) c1
from tab1 t
    left join tab2 t2 on t.id1 = t2.id1 and t.id2 = t2.id2 
group by t.id1, t.id2, t.a
```

Ideally I would like to have one single query without subqueries.

I managed to to this by subqueries but the solution is too slow. The above example is the follow up of [Pivot on joined tables SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875965/pivot-on-joined-tables-sql-server). (PS: The real model has almost 100 dynamic columns)

Comment: I am confused when I run your query I get the result above (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa12f/7) what is wrong with the result?  What should it be showing?

Comment: You are right. I mixed '0' with 'O'. I fixed post and your sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon Linoff your answer is correct but I didn't find a way to make it more dynamic. Fortunately I found a very generic solution. The key is to join the TAB1 with the grouped TAB2.

```
Select * from TAB2 A join 
   (Select ID1, ID2, MIN(ROOT), NAME from TAB2 
       group by ID2, ID1, NAME) B
   on A.ID1 = B.ID1 and B.ID2 = A.ID2 and A.NAME = B.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want only one row of `tab2` for each combination of `name, id1`.  The `row_number()` function can do this for you.  It assigns a sequence to each such group.  For your query, this sequence starts on the row (if any) where `root = 'A'`.

The full query is similar to your, except `tab2` is replaced with a subquery and the `on` condition has a slight modification:

```
select t.id1, t.id2, t.a,
    max(case when t2.name = 'C2' then t2.vint end) c2,
    max(case when t2.name = 'C1' then t2.vstring end) c1
from tab1 t left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, id1
                                order by (case when root = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from tab2 t2
     ) t2
     on t.id1 = t2.id1 and
        t.id2 = t2.id2 and
        t2.seqnum = 1
group by t.id1, t.id2, t.a
```

Comment: Thanks that looks interesting but I have up to 100 columns (like 'C1') and 20 roots (like 'A', 'B'). Can I applied your solution for this ?

Comment: @orwe . . . To quote from the OP:  "The only problem I have is how to pick up the correct value base on the ROOT column."  Are you trying to solve some other problem?